# What does the [] mean in the end of the function, in Javascript/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Could someone give me the direction where to look, or let me know what does the square brackets mean at the end of the function. Is there a different way how this can be re-written?

Code Example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (user) {
  router.push('/profile');
}
 }, [user]);
```

So the part which I am trying to understand is the [user].

Can this be re-written differently? What does it mean from the code perspective?

Comment: Read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: It’s an array literal

Comment: specifically, look at this part of the mentioned article:https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 1):

This is called an [*`Array` literal*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-initializer).

An [`Array`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-objects) is an object that represents the concept of an *indexable sequence of values*. A [*literal*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-primary-expression-literals) is a syntactic element of the programming language that allows one to *"literally" write down* an object value, as opposed to *programmatically constructing* it.

Here's an example of the difference between programmatically constructing an array and directly writing down the same array:

```ecmascript
const ary1 = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i);
const ary2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```